# Estimate value of harmonic function in the annulus

Tags: elliptic-pde, laplacian, harmonic-functions, laplace-equation, mean-value-theorem

Let $D = B_{2r}(0)\backslash \overline{B}_r(0)$. Assume $Lu = 0$ in $D$ where $L$ is a uniform elliptic operator with constant coefficients
$$
Lu = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}u_{x_i}u_{x_j}, \qquad \lambda |\xi|^2\leq a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j \leq \Lambda |\xi|^2
$$
with $u = 0$ on $\partial B_{2r}(0)$ and $u = 1$ on $\partial B_r(0)$.

I want to show
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(x_0) \geq \frac{C}{r}$$
for every point $x_0\in \partial \Omega$ and $C$ is independent of $r$.

I can use Hopf Lemma to reduce the problem to bounding
$$
u(x)\geq C > 0
$$
independent of $r$whenever $\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial \Omega) = \mathrm{const}$, say $\frac{r}{2}$.

---

For the Laplacian and 1-dimensional cases, it is true. Let's take a point $x\in \partial B_{2r}(0)$, then $\frac{x}{2}\in \partial B_r(0)$. In the 1D case, we can show that $u$ is linear and thus the midpoint of $\left[\frac{x}{2},x\right]$ satisfies
$$
 u\left(\frac{3x}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: This is true for Laplacian in any dimension since the harmonic function satisfying your boundary conditions is unique and can be explicitly written.  In the general case, you can use Harnack's inequality

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: For harmonic case $u(x)=a|x|^{2-n}+b$, where $a,b$ are constants determined from your boundary conditions.

Comment: I mean how to use Harnack inequality to get the result for the general case?